# How to handle "too broad", but interesting questions?

Tags: discussion, needs-more-focus

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46541911/android-antivirus-detecting-online-threat) today. In the current state, the question is too broad, at least in my opinion (there is no easy way to detect if something is acting malicious or not). However I think that this is an interesting question and the community could benefit from it, unless it is closed as "too broad".

I also remember finding questions in similar state that show research from the OP, but ended up as closed because there was no easy or clear answer (sometimes I think that we have to accept that some programming questions don't have a clear answer, but multiple users could create a starting point for research for feature users). If you agree with me, then how should we handle this kind of questions? Converting this posts to community wiki will represent a solution?

Comment: That's probably a better fit to ask at [SE Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). Not sure though.

Comment: @user0042 - it really isn't. Much too open ended.

Comment: @Oded I almost thought so.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should close these questions as... too broad.

Don't confuse "interesting" with "suitable for Stack Overflow".

There are a lot of questions that would be very interesting to people here that are not suitable to our Q&A format.

We discovered that during the early years of Stack Overflow - "best programming jokes?". Very interesting to people. Highly upvoted. But - there's no subjectively correct answer to that.

As a community we came to see that not everything belongs here.

Comment: I agree that it is not suitable for a Q&A format, but rather a forum. However, this kind of questions are sometimes "needed" and I was thinking that there might be a way to keep all the information on stackoverflow, not to split it between different sites.

Comment: Well, by virtue of not being suitable to a Q&A format, they don't belong on Stack Overflow... We tried Documentation, but that failed. Until we come up with a suitable format - these don't belong.